# STM32 enters stop mode on reset

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, interrupt

I am trying out stop mode in STM32F103x which is by the way a clone. I have a timer that counts up to five seconds and then sets a variable "goTosleep" = 1 on interrupt. Depending on the value of goTosleep I execute Stop command. I can exit the stop mode via EXTI. The problem is that the micro controller appears to enter stop mode upon reset. It exits stop mode fine when I give an interrupt on EXTI.

Here is my code.

```
#include "main.h"

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

uint8_t goTosleep = 0;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);
 
  while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(led_GPIO_Port, led_Pin);
    HAL_Delay(100);

    if(goTosleep == 1)
    {
      HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
      SystemClock_Config();
    }

  }

}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 7200-1;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 50000-1;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(led_GPIO_Port, led_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : led_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = led_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(led_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if(htim == &htim2)
  {
    goTosleep = 1;
  }

}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim2, 0);
  goTosleep = 0;
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: Is TIM2 interrupt configured correctly? What is the input clock frequency to the timer?

Comment: Also it is better to check the timer instance with htim->Instance == TIM2 predicate.

Comment: I have TIM2 global interrupt enabled. Input clock frequency to the timer is 72MHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that the timer interrupt routine runs once after starting the timer. So put a guard variable in the callback function:

```
uint8_t first_time = 0; // global
...
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
   if (first_time != 0)
   {
      if(htim == &htim2)
      {
         goTosleep = 1;
      }
   }
   first_time = 1;
}
```

Comment: first_time = 1 in the above code will never be assigned. Shouldn't I assign it some where inside the super loop?

Comment: Yes the guard variable is the solution. Note that for the above code,the first_time = 1 will never be set. So I assigned first_time = 1 inside the super loop and the code works. Thank you.

Comment: @launchin2space Good point. I think we can move the first_time = 1 out of the if. I will edit it. Now without using the superloop it should work.